# Set different audio output speakers for individual apps in Mac M1 Ventura

Tags: macos, audio, apple-m1

I'm using Mac M1 and looking for a solution to set different audio output speakers for individual apps. For example, I want audio that is playing in the browser come to my Mac speaker and audio that is playing in Spotify to come to my headphones at the same time. Is there any software, tool or script that can do that?